# Python module (keyboard) is not recognizing 'fn' key

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to use the function keys as a part of a keyboard shortcut with python (3.6) and it is failing to recognize the fn key event.

```
import keyboard
keyboard.press_and_release('fn+down')
```

Comment: Is this the `fn` key on *Macs*? Then this applies: *Works with Windows and Linux (requires sudo), with experimental OS X support (thanks @glitchassassin!).* File a bugreport with the project, perhaps?

Comment: No I am developing on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The [`keyboard` project](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) doesn't support the `fn` key, no. The [`keyboard.all_modifiers` set](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardall_modifiers) shows you what it can support.

On my Mac that produces:

```
>>> import keyboard
>>> keyboard.all_modifiers
{'alt', 'ctrl', 'windows', 'shift'}
```

Take into account that the `Fn` key *may not be visible to the OS*. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key#Technical_details):

> The Fn key is a form of meta-modifier key, in that it causes the operating system to see altered scancodes when other keys on the keyboard are pressed. This allows the keyboard to directly emulate a full-sized keyboard, so the operating system can use standard keymaps designed for a full-sized keyboard. **However, because the operating system has no notion of the Fn key, the key can not normally be remapped in software, unlike all other standard keyboard keys.**

(bold emphasis mine).

Apple Macs are the exception to this, I'm reasonably sure Windows is not.

Mac support is still experimental, from the project description:

> Works with Windows and Linux (requires sudo), **with experimental OS X support (thanks @glitchassassin!).**

(bold emphasis mine).

There already is an open issue with the project ([#221, *Unable to detect the top row of keys on Mac keyboard as function keys*](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/221)) tracking this.

For Windows and Linux, try to capture the keycode that `fn+down` actually translates to for the OS (with a [`keyboard.hook()` callback](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardhookcallback-suppressfalse-on_removelambda), see [this example](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/examples/pressed_keys.py)), then execute that keycode.

If `fn`+`down` controls your volume, just use `"volume down"` or integer  value `0xae` as the scan code:

```
keyboard.send(0xae)
```

Comment: are there any other libraries you are aware of that can be used in this instance?

Comment: @PrathamThukral: I strongly suspect that on Windows, there won't be *any* way to detect the Fn key, see the additional info I added.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. I ended up just using mouse events to select volume on the volume bar.

Comment: @PrathamThukral then just send the `volume down` key; scan code AE in hexadecimal. The module source code leads me to believe the name is directly supported already.