# How can I press the fn+f keys with Pynput?

Tags: python, pynput

I need to be able to press the Function key along with one of the f-keys with pynput, but it doesn't seem to recognize the function key as a keypress, nor does it recognize anything as a keypress when I hit both the function and one of the f-keys.

I'm trying to make a program that will change my keyboard backlight, and to do that I need to be able to have the program press fn+f3 and fn+f4, but I can't seem to make that work. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python module (keyboard) is not recognizing 'fn' key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012503/python-module-keyboard-is-not-recognizing-fn-key)

Comment: I already saw that when doing my own research prior to asking, and no, the solution there did not work for me.

Comment: Did you understand that there's probably no solution that will allow the `fn` key itself to be recognized? You have to instead capture/expect the resulting keyboard output that happens when pressing `fn` plus some f-key. Does that make sense?